# dynamic library using boost has undefined references when built on ARM architecture

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker, raspberry-pi

I have a C++ based dynamic library that I have built for the big 3 OSs that relies heavily on boost. Currently, I am compiling it for the raspberry pi. It took me a while to find the magic words to get the library to even build (-frepo as a compiler flag was the key, but I confess that I am not certain why this is the case).

Now, when I try to link to the library, I get an 'undefined reference' error to every boost call that my library makes, i.e.:

```
//`libmylib.so`: undeifined reference to `boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::thread_data_base>::shared_ptr()'
```

When I build `libmylib.so`, I also build a custom version of boost as `libboost.a`. This all compiles and links fine on other OSs and non-ARM architectures so I tried putting `-lboost` as one of the flags, but I still get the same plethora of undefined reference errors form `libmylib.so`.

Needless to say, all my paths are correct.

It seems like linking behaves a bit differently on the raspberry pi than it does on other linux systems. For example, I built a static library (`libmythread.a`) that uses `libpthread`. When I link to that `libmythread.a`, I also get undefined reference errors unless I also use `-lpthread` in the build recipe. On my Thinkpad running Fedora, I would never have to do this since I included `-lpthread` in the compilation of the static library `libmythread.a`.

I would love to find a tutorial or guide that explains these discrepancies. I would also love to overcome them!

I also tried the same build on a conventional linux machine and everything linked fine, no problem. At least I know that my build process is OK. This does open up the possibility, though, that the `-frepo` flag is doing something funny that I don't understand and that this could be the root of the problem.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong here but isn't it `-lboost_system` you should link to?

Comment: normally, yes, but I use a custom built (stripped down and name-magled) version that compiles as libboost.a. I guess I didn't make that very clear -- srry. I need to try to link against regular old boost, but I suspect it won't help.

Comment: can you put a `-L /dir where libboost is at/` ? How are you cross-compiling or are you compiling on target?

Comment: I have the _l/dir where libboost is at/ already in the makefile. I have been building the application on target as it is very small, but I initially built my libraries using arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-g++ on a Ubuntu desktop. I tried building the library on target as well, same result. I am now trying to build the application via cross-compiler and see what happens. I will start a build conventional system boost on target right before I go home tonight so I can try that too -- it takes about 4 hours apparently.

Comment: Have you tried with the raspian image, you could do a `sudo apt-get install boost` maybe you won't have to wait those 4 hours. There is a yocto meta-layer for raspeberry-pi that you also could use to make sure that the libraries are cross-compiled correctly. In general you shouldn't compile on target as it usually a quite time consuming task. BTW. What's your constraints on the system, do you have limited SD card space?

Comment: Yeah... I don't think you can get boost from aptitude on pi. Terrible shame. There isn't really a constraint on the system. The boost dance is done to avoid conflicts with 3rd party apps that use my library. This isn't really necessary for the pi, but reconfiguring the build setup is nontrivial. In general, I believe my cross-compiling is working correctly (at least I have that going for me...)

Comment: I got a little bit afraid there for a moment but it seems that boost is available, this is from my Raspberry Pi2: `sudo apt-get install libboost-system-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libboost-system1.49-dev libboost-system1.49.0 libboost1.49-dev`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! I figured it out and post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In the end, the trouble stemmed from the `-frepo` flag. This was necessary to compile a file called `legacy_abi.cpp` that is part of my library to allow third party developers using older and more exotic OSs/compilers. This isn't needed on the Pi, so I just removed it from the offending file from the build, dropped the `-frepo` flag and happy happy.

One final note, aptitude (for Pi, anyway) only supplies boost up to 1.49 (as far as I can tell). My project requires boost >= 1.50. This is an inherited project, so I'm still discovering all its little idiosyncracies.